# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported when file uploading

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my spring application, occurs 'HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported' error when uploading file through the JSP page.But the records already saved in the DB are listing perfectly on JSP page.I used spring security in my application and without applying spring security it works fine. Why it is not working after applying spring security?

My spring-servlet.xml is:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- It register the beans in context and scan the annotations inside beans and activate them -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="mgr" />


   <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- This allow for dispatching requests to Controllers -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"
        cache-period="31556926" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"
        cache-period="31556927" />
     <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- This helps in mapping the logical view names to directly view files under a certain pre-configured directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean> 

    <!-- This resolves messages from resource bundles for different locales -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

    <!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory;
         rather than application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="mgr.model" />
      <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
   </bean>
   <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
   <!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
        configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mgr" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>

    <!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access.
        JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean" />
   </bean>


   <!-- responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power annotation-driven transaction management;
        such as when @Transactional methods are invoked -->
   <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml is:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/addUser**" access="hasRole('View')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/addPhoto**" access="hasRole('View')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/addCategory**" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/addRole**" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/addPrivilege**" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/index**" access="hasRole('Admin')"/>
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/login" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf/>
    </http>
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select user_name,password, isActive from mgr_user where user_name=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select usr.user_name,role.name
             from mgr_user usr
                  join mgr_user_cat_role cr on(cr.ucat_id = usr.ucat_id and cr.isassign = 1)
                  join mgr_user_category cat on(cat.id = cr.ucat_id)
                  join mgr_user_role role on(role.id = cr.urole_id)
             where usr.user_name=?" />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration for the DispatcherServlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

DaoImpl is:

```
    /**
     * 
     */

package mgr.dao;

import mgr.model.Document;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * @author Charith
 *
 */
@Component
public class DocumentDaoImpl implements DocumentDao{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void save(Document document) {
        em.persist(document);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional  
    public List<Document> list() {

        List<Document> documents = null;
        try {
            documents = (List<Document>)em.createQuery("from Document").getResultList();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return documents;
    }
    @Transactional  
    public Document get(Integer id) {
        return (Document)em.find(Document.class, id);
    }
    @Transactional
    public void remove(Integer id) {
        Document document = (Document)em.find(Document.class, id);
         em.remove(document);
    }

}
```

Controller.java is:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package mgr.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialException;

import mgr.dao.DocumentDao;
import mgr.model.Document;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

/**
 * @author Charith
 *
 */
@Controller
public class DocumentController {
    @Autowired
    private DocumentDao documentDao;


    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {

        try {
            map.put("document", new Document());
            map.put("documentList", documentDao.list());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "documents";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/savePhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("document") Document document,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        System.out.println("Name:" + document.getName());
        System.out.println("Desc:" + document.getDescription());
        System.out.println("File:" + file.getName());
        System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

        // Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());
        Blob blob;
        try {
            blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(
                    IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream()));
            document.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
            document.setContent(blob);
            document.setContentType(file.getContentType());
        } catch (SerialException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            documentDao.save(document);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/download/{documentId}")
    public String download(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("documentId"+documentId);
        Document doc = documentDao.get(documentId);
        System.out.println("file name :"+doc.getFilename());
        try {
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\""
                    + doc.getFilename() + "\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
            IOUtils.copy(doc.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{documentId}")
    public String remove(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId) {

        documentDao.remove(documentId);

        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Jsp file is :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document Manager - viralpatel.net</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Document Manager</h2>

<h3>Add new document</h3>
 <c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" var="logoutUrl" />
    <!-- csrt for log out-->
    <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
      <input type="hidden" 
        name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function formSubmit() {
            document.getElementById("logoutForm").submit();
        }
    </script>

    <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            Welcome : ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a
                href="javascript:formSubmit()"> Logout</a>
        </h2>
    </c:if>
<form:form method="post" action="savePhoto" commandName="document" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
        <td><form:textarea path="description" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="content">Document</form:label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></input></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Document"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>

<br/>
<h3>Document List</h3>
<c:if  test="${!empty documentList}">
<table class="data">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${documentList}" var="document">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">${document.name}</td>
        <td width="250px">${document.description}</td>
        <td width="20px">
            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/download/${document.id}.html"><img
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/save_icon.gif" border="0"
                title="Download this document"/></a> 

            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/remove/${document.id}.html"
                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this document?')"><img
                src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/delete_icon.gif" border="0"
                title="Delete this document"/></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<intercept-url pattern="/savePhoto**" access="hasRole('VIEW')" method="POST"/>
```

to your spring-security.xml

Answer (score 0):

I added below line, and now it works fine

```
<form:form method="post" action="savePhoto?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" commandName="document" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Even I didn't add '${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}' in other jsp pages, they works fine.Pls explain me.